# Aligning formulas with equation

Tags: math-mode, equations, align

Using the equation environment, I am listing various formulas underneath each other. However, the variables are not aligned:

```latex
\begin{equation}
  \begin{aligned}
    V = \{ & w_{v}^{V}\mid v\in \{1,2,\dots,|V|\};\\
           & w_{v}^{V} \neq w_{v'}, \forall v,v' \in \{1,2,\dots,|V|\} \}.
  \end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
  \begin{aligned}
    T = \{w_{n,k}^{T}\mid  w_{n,k}^{T} \in V ; n\in\{1,2,\dots,N\}; \\
    k\in\{1,2,\dots,K\}\}. \\
  \end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
  \begin{aligned}
    C = \{f_{v}\mid f_{v} \in  \mathbb{Z_{+}}; \forall v \in \{1,2, \dots , |V|\}  \}.
  \end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
  \begin{aligned}
    C'= \{f_{v'}^{'}\mid f_{v'}^{'}\geq c_{v'+1}^{'} \forall v' \in \{1,2,...|V|-1\} \}.
  \end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
  \begin{aligned}
    IC_{v'}= \{v'|f_{v'} = c_{k} \forall v',k \in \{1,2,...,|V|\}  \}.
  \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\\
Additionally, the function $M(w_{v}^{V})$ maps a word $w_{v}^{V}$ to the set $IC_{v'}$.
\begin{equation}
  \begin{aligned}
    M(w_{v}^{V}): w_{v}^{V} \rightarrow IC_{v'}
  \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
```

How can I align these?

[image]

Comment: Please extend your code3 fragment to complete small document called MWE (Minimal working Example), which reproduce your problem. Also see comments and solution on your previous question. This question seems to be duplicatew to it.

Comment: Please explain what exactly you mean by `not aligned`? What is suppose to be aligned here? All your `aligned` has no alignment points in then. Additionally, I combine all those `equation` into a single `align`.

Comment: @Zarko, this is not a duplicate; here my question is about aligning different equations. My previous question was about properly showing a single formula without breaking out of the column space. 
egreg his answer is what I was looking for.

Comment: But, the concept is very the same ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to nest `split` in `align`.

I presume you're using a two-column format, so I add a negative space (tailored so that the equations fit).

1. I changed the trailing periods into commas, except the last one
2. I removed the useless `aligned` in the last equation
3. Don't use `\\` after an equation
4. `...` should be `\dots`
5. The outer braces have become `\big`
6. Fixed one `|` to be `\mid` as well
7. Changed all `^{'}` into `'`

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\newcommand{\antiquad}{\hspace{-0.8em}}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
  \begin{split}
  \antiquad
    V = \bigl\{ & w_{v}^{V}\mid v\in \{1,2,\dots,|V|\};\\
                & w_{v}^{V} \neq w_{v'}, \forall v,v' \in \{1,2,\dots,|V|\}
        \bigr\},
  \end{split}
\\
  \begin{split}
  \antiquad
    T = \bigl\{ & w_{n,k}^{T}\mid  w_{n,k}^{T} \in V ; n\in\{1,2,\dots,N\}; \\
                & k\in\{1,2,\dots,K\}
        \bigr\},
  \end{split}
\\
  \antiquad
    C = \bigl\{ & f_{v}\mid f_{v} \in  \mathbb{Z_{+}}; \forall v \in \{1,2, \dots , |V|\}
        \bigr\},
\\
  \antiquad
    C'= \bigl\{ & f_{v'}'\mid f_{v'}'\geq c_{v'+1}' \forall v' \in \{1,2,\dots,|V|-1\}
        \bigr\},
\\
  \antiquad
    IC_{v'}= \bigl\{ & v' \mid f_{v'} = c_{k} \forall v',k \in \{1,2,\dots,|V|\}
             \bigr\}.
\end{align}
Additionally, the function $M(w_{v}^{V})$ maps a word $w_{v}^{V}$ to the set $IC_{v'}$.
\begin{equation}
    M(w_{v}^{V})\colon w_{v}^{V} \rightarrow IC_{v'}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

On the other hand, I see that the equation numbers in your picture are in Times, so I recommend using `newtx`.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
  \begin{split}
    V = \bigl\{ & w_{v}^{V}\mid v\in \{1,2,\dots,|V|\};\\
                & w_{v}^{V} \neq w_{v'}, \forall v,v' \in \{1,2,\dots,|V|\}
        \bigr\},
  \end{split}
\\
  \begin{split}
    T = \bigl\{ & w_{n,k}^{T}\mid  w_{n,k}^{T} \in V ; n\in\{1,2,\dots,N\}; \\
                & k\in\{1,2,\dots,K\}
        \bigr\},
  \end{split}
\\
    C = \bigl\{ & f_{v}\mid f_{v} \in  \mathbb{Z_{+}}; \forall v \in \{1,2, \dots , |V|\}
        \bigr\},
\\
    C'= \bigl\{ & f_{v'}'\mid f_{v'}'\geq c_{v'+1}' \forall v' \in \{1,2,\dots,|V|-1\}
        \bigr\},
\\
    IC_{v'}= \bigl\{ & v' \mid f_{v'} = c_{k} \forall v',k \in \{1,2,\dots,|V|\}
             \bigr\}.
\end{align}
Additionally, the function $M(w_{v}^{V})$ maps a word $w_{v}^{V}$ to the set $IC_{v'}$.
\begin{equation}
    M(w_{v}^{V})\colon w_{v}^{V} \rightarrow IC_{v'}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

No need for negative spacing, because Times is narrower than Computer Modern.